# weird, white, glossy looking rendered view mode

Tags: rendering

I'm super new to Blender and I need some help. I've been following a youtube tutorial "how to make a donut" and everything was alright till the rendered view mode. I don't know why, but in rendered view mode my donut has a very weird, white, 'glossy' look. When I switch to any other mode, everything is fine, donut looks normal. I didn't do anything to solve the problem, because I have no idea what the problem is. I would really appreciate some help :)))

here's a foto for better understanding the problem [image]

Comment: can you send the . blend file?

Comment: What kind of GPU do you have, and are your drivers up to date?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you have a **light source** (point, sun or something else) that is *way* too bright.

Try and lower your light sources while in rendering mode and see if anything happens. Normally, lights only affect rendering mode, so my guess is maybe you tweaked the lights in another mode, went too far, and now everything is too bright.